# Batch Georeferencing in ArcMap/ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, batch

I have about 50 pdf maps that I would like to batch georeference and/or georectify. I've saved one as a jpg and georeferenced it manually and would like to automate the rest which are in the same location and have the same extent.

[image]

The density gradient will change in each case, but the map (saved as jpg now) will have the same extent for all 50 cases.

Does anyone know of a link to a **step-by-step** tutorial that deals with batch processing in Arcmap 10.2 only? I'm thinking of using the [Warp from File code](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Warp_From_File/00170000015v000000/) or possibly the [Autoregistration](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000240000000) option, but am not sure where to start?

The sample code is:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.WarpFromFile_management(
"\\cpu\data\raster.img", "\\cpu\data\warp_out.tif",
"\\cpu\data\gcpfile.txt", "POLYORDER2", "BILINEAR")
```

Comment: Do they occupy the same space? Are the files adjacent to one another?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a link to the Wrap from File code that you mention, please?

Comment: The physical files are located within the same folder. The map data occupies the exact same space across all 50 examples.

Answer (score 18):

In your case (jpg rasters and exact same extent for all rasters) the Warp From File tool is just fine.

If you haven't saved a link file yet you should do this first:
 Georeference one raster in ArcMap, click the View Link Table button and save the links to a text file using the Save button:

[image: View Link Table]
Then there are different options:

- **Batch**: You can use the Warp from file tool in Batch mode by right-clicking it in the toolbox:

[image: Batch]

- **arcpy**: Change the variables in the following code and run it the way you like. I would just copy/paste it in the Python Window in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.

> ```
> import arcpy, os
>
> # Variables
> arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\InFolder"    # Folder with rasters to be georeferenced"
> OutF = r"C:\OutFolder"                  # Output folder
> Suf = "_georef"                         # Suffix added to the output (if necessary)
> Ext = ".jpg"                            # Format of the output rasters
> LinkFile = r"C:\linkfile.txt"           # Your link file
> Transf = "POLYORDER0"                   # Transformation type - to choose from:
>                                         #"POLYORDER0", "POLYORDER1", "POLYORDER2", "POLYORDER3", "ADJUST SPLINE" or "PROJECTIVE"
> Resampl = "NEAREST"                     # Resampling type - to choose from:
>                                         # "NEAREST", "BILINEAR", "CUBIC" or "MAJORITY"
>
> # Process
> ListRas = arcpy.ListRasters()
> for ras in ListRas:
>     basename = arcpy.Describe(ras).baseName
>     outpath = os.path.join(OutF, basename + Suf + Ext)
>     arcpy.WarpFromFile_management(ras, outpath, LinkFile, Transf, Resampl)
>     print "Georeferenced {} successfully".format(basename)
> ```

- **ModelBuilder**: you can iterate over the rasters with the Rasters Iterator (Insert > Iterators > Rasters). Use %Name%.png in the output path to get your outputs named the same way as the inputs (or %Name%_suffix.png):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it this evening and will update with the results.