# Script for auto registration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, georeferencing

I have a large list of raster images (>600) I would like to automatically georeference to a source image.

I can do this in ArcGIS 10.2 using the Auto Registration tool for each image but looking for a way to iterate it in ModelBuilder/python script.

Is there an arcpy command or similar for the auto registration tool?

Comment: This might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107008/batch-georeferencing-in-arcmap-10-2

Comment: Full story please. Are they in the same place? Do you have some sort of regularity, e.g. coded in names or mesh of extents?

Comment: You said you have a large list ? My question to you is where does they came from ?

Comment: The 600+ images are roughly similar (sequential names). They are frame grabs from a video taken obliquely from a drone. Drone moves +- 5 m. So I cant use warp from file... Im actually after the code behind the auto registration tool. I would like to create automatic links between each of the images and a reference one, sort the links by total RMSE and choose the best 10 or so and apply a 2nd order polynomial transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Register Raster tool in ArcToolbox, and you know the input parameters for the tool you can place all your files in a single directory, get all the files, and feed them into the tool in a loop.
Here is some untested code to get you started...

```
import arcpy, traceback, sys, os

folderofimagesfiles = r"Z:\GISpublic\GerryG\Restoration\MackayFlight20151202\Images"

try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderofimagesfiles):
            for file in files:
                thisfile = os.path.join(root, dirs, file)
                arcpy.RegisterRaster_management(thisfile, "Place", "Your", "Parameters", "Here")

except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
    arcpy.AddError(msgs) 
    print msgs
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    print pymsg + "\n"
    print msgs
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually referring to the Auto registration icon from the Georeferencing toolbar