# Georeferencing *.tiff to given feature geometry automatically?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, gdal, pyqgis

I´ve got the task to georeference an tiff image to the referencing polygon footprint (Polygon).
I have found a lot of ways to do get the footprint from a raster but I could not find a way to use pyqgis or gdal to do it the other way around. Hints using ESRI ArcGIS are also welcome.

[image]

Comment: Place Ground Control Points to the corners of the image. You can test the process with gdal_translate and -gcp parameters http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html before doing the same with Python.

Comment: In arcpy see WarpFromFile_Management. It requires ground control points as well. Here is a discussion: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107008/batch-georeferencing-in-arcmap-10-2